# R markdown / xfun and knitr packages

Tags: r, package, r-markdown, knitr

I am new to RMarkdown and I cannot manage to knit and create a pdf or power point document.
My xfun version is 3.0 and a pop up message tells me that I need at least the 3.9 version. I am trying to update the version in the right package tab.

[image]

Yet the version does not get updated after i update the package. (Here is the update code below)

```
    > install.packages("xfun")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
xfun   0.30   0.40              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/xfun_0.30.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 398028 bytes (388 KB)
downloaded 388 KB

package ‘xfun’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpieVCp3\downloaded_packages
```

To knit, I need to install knitr, which does not work because I need this xfun update. When I try to install knitr, this is the code I get.

```
    > install.packages("knitr")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘xfun’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
      binary source needs_compilation
xfun    0.30   0.40              TRUE
knitr   1.38   1.44             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/xfun_0.30.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 398028 bytes (388 KB)
downloaded 388 KB

package ‘xfun’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpieVCp3\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘knitr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/knitr_1.44.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 898526 bytes (877 KB)
downloaded 877 KB

* installing *source* package 'knitr' ...
** package 'knitr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.30 is being loaded, but >= 0.39 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'knitr'
* removing 'C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/knitr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpieVCp3\downloaded_packages’
```

I tried to uninstall/install R and R studio, tried to uninstall/install the different packages, tried rebooting my computer even, but nothing works.

I have the R version 06.2. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried installing Rtools, as the warning message suggests?

Comment: Yes I have but the warning message is the same. It keeps saying that Rtools is required when I just installed it into my computer.

Comment: If you're using windows have you put R tools on [`PATH`](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html)?